# Mybatis XMLGregorianCalendar handler

Tags: java, mybatis

Mapper File
employeeMapper.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.xxxx.sample.test.dao.TestDAO">
<select id="selectEmployee" parameterType="int" resultMap="com.viasat.sample.domain.CreateDate" >
select createdate from employee where id = #{id}
</select>
</mapper>
```

Mapper Interface
TestDAO.java

```
public interface TestDAO {
public com.viasat.sample.domain.CreateDate selectEmployee(int id);
}
```

POJO Bean
CreateDate.java

```
public class CreateDate {
private XMLGregorianCalendar createdate;
public XMLGregorianCalendar getCreatedate() {
return createdate;
}
public void setCreatedate(XMLGregorianCalendar createdate) {
this.createdate = createdate;
}
}
```

Main Method
MainClass.java

```
public class MainClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
try {
TestDAO tm = session.getMapper(TestDAO.class);
Map emp = tm.selectEmployee(123);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
session.close();
}
}
}
```

Issue: The date value(createdate) retrieved from is not mapping/setting to XMLGregorianCalendar type createdate in CreateDate bean. It works fine if the data type of createdate is Date. To be brief DATE datatype is not setting in XMLGregorianCalendar type in Mybatis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Custom Handler:

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement; 
import java.sql.Date; 
import java.sql.PreparedStatement; 
import java.sql.ResultSet; 
import java.sql.SQLException; 
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar; 
import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType; 
import org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeHandler; 
public class CustomDateTypeHandler implements TypeHandler { 
@Override 
public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Object parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) 
throws SQLException { 
if (null != parameter) { 
long time = ((XMLGregorianCalendar) parameter).toGregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis(); 
Date date = new java.sql.Date(time); 
ps.setDate(i, date); 
} 
else { 
ps.setTimestamp(i, null); 
} 
} 
@Override 
public Object getResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException { 
Date date = rs.getDate(columnName); 
if (null == date) { 
return null; 
} 
XMLGregorianCalendar date2 = null;
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(date);
try {
date2 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
} catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return date2;
} 
@Override 
public Object getResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException { 
return "";
} 
}
```

Add this handler in Mybatis Configuration xml file:

```
<typeHandler handler="com.viasat.cmdb.common.utils.CustomDateTypeHandler" javaType="javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar" />
</typeHandlers>
```